# How can I apply one-hot encoding correctly in Keras for a 2D pixel image classification CNN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a 2D RGB pixel-based image classification problem via convolution neural networks (CNN). I will fully describe my problem and provide as much details as possible.

I split my training and validation as follows:

```
x_trn, x_val, y_trn, y_val = train_test_split(img, msk,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

where `img` is an array of `(number_of_image_patches x image_rows x image_columns x number_of_image_channels`). So I have 200 RGB(i.e., 3 channels) image patches at `128x128` each. Thus, the `img` array is a `(200 x 128 x 128 x 3)`.

Also, `msk` is an array containing the class labels of each image patch that will be used to train the CNN and has a size of `(200 x 128 x 128)`. Each `msk` patch is a `128x128` array with the class labels. In my problem, I have `7 classes`.

Since my problem is a multi-class classification, I am using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function. And `softmax` as my activation function for output results. My full CNN model can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8871bec87bcdd5375326e9511cec0718).

The shape of `y_trn` is `(160 x 128 x 128)` and `y_val` is `(40 x 128 x 128)`.

Now, `categorical_crossentropy` requires that the `y_trn` and `y_val` variables to be one-hot encoded. I do this as follows:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_trn= to_categorical(y_trn, num_classes=len(np.unique(y_trn)))
y_val= to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=len(np.unique(y_val)))
```

The new shape of `y_trn` after applying one-hot encoding is `(2621440 x 7)` due to the fact that I have `7 classes`. The `2621440` comes from the multiplication of `160x128x128`

Afterwards, I do the following to train/fit the CNN model:

```
model =  my_CNN_unet()

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet6_test_{epoch:02d}.hdf5')
model.fit(x_trn, y_trn, batch_size=50, epochs=3, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint], validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_138 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2621440 , 7)
```

This means that my one-hot encoding is obviously not being applied correctly as it expects a the one-hot array to be 4D. I am assuming the correct size of `y_trn` should be: `(160 x 128 x 128 x 7)`.

I am new to both Python and Keras and not sure how to overcome this error. Any insights are welcome.

Comment: why is msk 200x128x128? Are you trying to label every pixel of every image as one of the 7 classes?

Comment: yes...it is a 2d semantic segmentation problem

Comment: Not familiar with this but have you tried reshaping y_train after one hot encoding as you mentioned or is it possible to reshape msk?

Comment: would you agree with my assumption that the correct size of `y_trn` should be: (160 x 128 x 128 x 7) , which would then be fed to `model.fit` ?

Comment: y_trns shape would depend on both the problem and how you designed your output, is your final layer - 'conv10' returning 128x128x7? .. if so, you are right about y_trn shape.

Comment: I think your y_trn is as you said and the in the output layer, you should make your final convolution layer to output 7 features and reshape feature into 128x128 and then softmax, so you get 128x128x7 and then you could use the y_trn

Comment: @Littleone based on my CNN [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8871bec87bcdd5375326e9511cec0718), how can I do specify to output 7 features? I am not too familiar.

Comment: Yea, that was poorly explained.. Check [this](https://github.com/mrubash1/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/models/unet.py) out. Similar to your needs. I would also recommend doing model.summary() and working out if the dimensions match.

Comment: @Littleone Would you recommend I use from lines 70-76 so that my new CNN model will be as follows: `conv10 = Convolution2D(7, 1, 1, name='conv_10_1')(conv9)`  

    `output = Reshape((128* 128, 7))(conv10)`  
    `output = Activation('softmax')(output)`  
    `output = Reshape((128, 128, 7))(output)`  

    `model = Model(input=inputs, output=output)`

Comment: Try it. Again, your dimensions might not be the same as his.

Comment: I just tried it. The model.fit runs and is optimizing across numerous epochs. Does it mean the dimensions match ok? Or can it just be coincidence?

Comment: @Littleone when I do `model.summary` , what should I check to make sure the dimensions are ok and they are matching?

Comment: Yes, sounds like it's working.